# I am getting NotRegistered Error in GCM response

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My device is returning a registration id in fact it is working perfect a hour ago but suddenly i am getting NotRegistered Error and the device is still Returning a registration ID.
 Also it is working with other ID's
No Idea what is going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Try to register again to GCM (make sure your device is really registering and not re-using a registration ID previously stored in local storage). Then try to send a message to the device and see if it arrives or if you get any errors on the device. Some errors cause the device to get unregistered, which will return NotRegistered to your server the next time you try to send a message to it.